# My program loops forever and does only a half of what I told it to do

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I'm new to programming and I started to make my own Fire Emblem level up calculator, but for some reason it loops infinitely. I can't find an answer.
Could you look for any mistakes in my code, please?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<windows.h>
int main () {
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int level ,str , skl, lck, def, res, inc, hp, spd, nr ;
char cha[10];
nr=1;
cout<< "Which character?";
cin>> cha ;
cout<< "You chose" << cha << "." << endl << "What level do you want him/her to be?";
cin>> level ;
        if (cha[6] = 'Dieck' ) {
            hp = 26;
            str = 9;
            skl = 12;
            spd = 10;
            lck = 4;
            def = 6;
            res = 1;
            while (level > 0) {

            if (rand() % 100 < 90) {
                inc=1;
                //cout<< "HP increased by" << inc ;
                hp+1;

        }
            if (rand() % 100 < 40) {
                inc=1;
            //  cout<< "Strenght/Magic increased by" << inc ;
                str+1;  
        }
            if (rand() % 100 < 40) {
                inc=1;
                //cout<< "Skill increased by" << inc ;
                skl+1;  
        }
            if (rand() % 100 < 30) {
                inc=1;
            //  cout<< "Speed increased by" << inc ;
                spd+1;  
        }
            if (rand() % 100 < 35) {
                inc=1;
                //cout<< "Luck increased by" << inc ;
                lck+1;  
        }
            if (rand() % 100 < 20) {
                inc=1;
                //cout<< "Defense increased by" << inc ;
                def+1;  
        }
            if (rand() % 100 < 15) {
                inc=1;
                //cout<< "Resistance increased by" << inc ;
                res+1;

        }
        nr+1;
        level-1;
        //cout<<"NR."<< nr << " New stats (in order) HP/STR/SKL/SPD/LCK/DEF/RES " << hp <<" "<< str <<" "<< skl <<" "<< spd <<" "<< lck <<" "<< def <<" "<< res << endl; 
        Sleep(1);

        }
        cout<< "Stats "<< "HP/STR/SKL/SPD/LCK/DEF/RES " << hp <<" "<< str <<" "<< skl <<" "<< spd <<" "<< lck <<" "<< def <<" "<< res << endl;
        return 0 ;
}
```

}

Comment: ***if (cha[6] = 'Dieck' ) {*** is wrong for more than 1 reason. I would look at your compiler warnings!

Comment: Char is 1 byte mate. Use the strcmp if you want to compare the array against something.

Comment: Your code will never compile, you need to assign `nr+1; level-1;` in some variable, like this `nr++; level--;

Comment: It loops infinitly because level is never decreased level - 1; is no assignment.

Comment: Please right-click your project in solution explorer, select Properties, open out the C/C++ properties, click on General and set Warning Level to 4.  Make sure you select All Configurations and All Platforms, so it's set to level 4 for both debug and release.  I have no idea why Microsoft default this setting to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue you have is `cha[6] = 'Dieck'`

`cha[6]` is a single character such as 'D' or 'i' but not the whole thing. Also `=` sets `cha[6]` equal to `'Dieck'` which can't happen because `'Dieck'` is not a valid character. To compare them you'd need `==` but you can only compare one character at a time like `cha[0] == 'D'`

Really you should make your input a string, and use the compare() method of the string.

```
std::string input;
// stuff
cin >> input;

if (input.compare("Dieck") == 0)
{
   // more stuff
}
```

Comment: Although correct, this does not answer the question about the loop.

Comment: Is it possible to do `input == "Dieck"`?  I never really use the `compare` function.  Perhaps it's because I learned C++ before Java.

Answer (score 2):

## 2011 version

`std::string`s, `std::bind`s initializer lists, modern random number generators, `auto` variable typing. Shucks, even a few oldies-but-goodies like classes and error checking the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

// prep random number generator to simulate a 100 sided die
std::default_random_engine engine; // not being fancy here. Just using default RNG
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform(1,100);// random from 1 to 100
auto d100 = std::bind ( uniform, engine ); // Convenience wrapper

void upstat(int & stat, // stat to increase
            int chance, // odds of increase
            int inc, // amount to increase
            const std::string & statname)
{
    if (d100() <= chance)
    { //less than or equal because I decided to emulate a d100.
      // if the range was 0 - 99, only < would be necessary.
      // such is the cost of slavishly adhering to dice conventions.
//        std::cout<< statname << " increased by " << inc << std::endl;
        stat += inc;
    }
}

class Character
{
public:
    Character(const std::string & name,
              int level,
              int HP,
              int str,
              int skl,
              int spd,
              int lck,
              int def,
              int res):
                  mName(name), mLevel(level), mStr(str), mSkl(skl), mLck(lck),
                  mDef(def), mRes(res), mHP(HP), mSpd(spd)
    {

    }

    void levelup()
    {
        upstat(mHP, 90, 1, "HP");
        upstat(mStr, 40, 1, "Strength/Magic");
        upstat(mSkl, 40, 1, "Skill");
        upstat(mSpd, 30, 1, "Speed");
        upstat(mLck, 35, 1, "Luck");
        upstat(mDef, 20, 1, "Defense");
        upstat(mRes, 15, 1, "Resistance");
        mLevel++;
    }

    // a couple useful getters
    const std::string & getName()
    {
        return mName;
    }
    unsigned int getLevel()
    {
        return mLevel;
    }

    // out stream operator
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                                     const Character & ch)
    {
        out << "Stats " << "HP/STR/SKL/SPD/LCK/DEF/RES " <<
                ch.mHP << " " <<
                ch.mStr << " " <<
                ch.mSkl << " " <<
                ch.mSpd << " " <<
                ch.mLck << " " <<
                ch.mDef << " " <<
                ch.mRes << std::endl;
        return out;
    }

private:
    std::string mName;
    unsigned int mLevel;
    int mStr;
    int mSkl;
    int mLck;
    int mDef;
    int mRes;
    int mHP;
    int mSpd;
};

// name-indexed list of characters. Currently only contains Dieck.
std::map<std::string, Character> charlist{{"Dieck",{"Dieck",1, 26, 9, 12, 10, 4, 6, 1}}};

int main()
{
    unsigned int finalLevel;
    std::string cha; // using a string rather than a char array. Much less error prone.
    std::cout << "Which character?" <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> cha;
    auto found = charlist.find(cha); // look in charlist for selected character
    if (found != charlist.end()) // find returns end of list if not found
    {
        std::cout << "You chose " << found->second.getName() << "." << std::endl <<
                     found->second << std::endl; //optional. Print stats
        for ( ; ; ) // Stay a while. Stay FOREVER! Muhuhahahahaha!
        {
            std::cout << "What level do you want him/her to be?" << std::endl;
            if (std::cin >> finalLevel)
            {
                while (found->second.getLevel() < finalLevel)
                { // keep calling characer's level up routine until desired level reached
                  // or do nothing if the character is already a higher level.   
                    found->second.levelup();
                }
                std::cout << found->second << std::endl; //optional. Print new stats
                break; // breaks the infinite loop if input was good
            }
            else
            { // bad user input. Call user names until they get it right.
                std::cout << "Valid positive numbers only, please." << std::endl;
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
            }
        }
    }
    else
    { // didn't find character. Do nothing.
      // Should probably prompt to create new character here.
        std::cout << "Character " << cha << " not found." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## 2020 Rethink

Doesn't change much, but replaces `std::bind` with a Lambda expression.

```cpp
std::default_random_engine engine; 
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform(1,100);
auto d100 = std::bind ( uniform, engine );
```

is replaced with

```cpp
auto d100 = [](){
    // all bundled up inside the lambda. No globals leaking out
    static std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()}; 
    // explicitly specified the generator. Fewer surprises.
    // this can be expensive, so it might be worth exposing gen and sharing it with 
    // other die-rolling lamdas

    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform(1,100); // random from 1 to 100

    return uniform(gen); // return result
};
```

Comment: `for ( ; ; ) // Stay a while. Stay FOREVER! Muhuhahahahaha!`

and

`// such is the cost of slavishly adhering to dice conventions.`

+1 for those two lines alone. I'd give it +2 if I could.

Answer (score 1):

`level-1;` computes the value of `level-1` and then throws it away, doing essentially nothing. As such, the value in `level` is never updated and you're stuck with an infinite loop (you are also doing this with all of your variable updates, be careful!)

If you want to *decrement* the value of level (reduce it by one), you can do any of the following:

```
level = level - 1;
level -= 1;
level--;
```

**Furthermore,**  `if(cha[6] = 'Dieck')` is not correct on several fronts. You could perhaps do

```
if(strcmp(cha, "Dieck") == 0) { //...
```

If you make sure to `#include <cstring>`

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems which may cause compilation error.

```
nr+1;
level-1;
```

You have to assign them into some variable. Try this:

```
nr = nr+1;
```

or

```
nr++;
```

and

```
level = level -1;
```

or

```
level--;
```

now the `while` loop is not going to *loop infinite*.

Second problem is

```
if (cha[6] = 'Dieck' )
```

Note that, `=` is an assignment operator, not an *equal operator*. Equal operator looks like *double equal* `==`. As you want to compare whether `cha` is equal to `Dieck` or not, try this:

```
if (strcmp (cha, "Dieck") == 0)
```

But you need to include `#include<cstring>` for that.

Reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Comment: Please don't encourage C-style strings.  Recommend C++ `std::string` instead.