# array of function pointer pointing to functions of a different class

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

I have a class MyClass. In it, I want to create an array of function pointer and initialize the array with the functions of another class (MemberClass).
MyClass has a pointer to MemberClass as member.
but I get this compile time error
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall MyMemberClass::* )(void)' to 'F'

```
//This class has the function that I want to create a function pointer to
class MemberClass
{

private:

int myValue1;
int myValue2;

public: 

int GetValue1() //I want to point to this function from a function pointer in another class
{

    return myvalue1;
}

int GetValue2() //I want to point to this function from a function pointer in another class
{

    return myvalue2;
}


}




//This has array of function pointer that I want to point to member function of another class

Class MyClass
{

typedef void(*F)();


private:
MemberClass* mclass;
F[] f;
Process();
}

.cpp

MyClass::MyClass()
{
f[2] = {&MemberClass::GetValue1, &MemberClass::GetValue2} //This line throws error

//error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall MyMemberClass::* )(void)' to 'F'

}

void     MyClass::Processing()
{

//This is how I am hoping to use the function pointer array
F[Index]();

}
```

Comment: [Save yourself some pain and read this link on `std::bind`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: [Also read this piece on method pointers.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) I doubt SO can do a much better explanation of what you've run into.

Comment: A simple function pointer is not sufficient to represent an member function. Instead of `typedef void(*F)()` you can technically do `typedef void(MemberClass:*F)()`, but the whole thing sounds fishy. Member function pointers are very seldom the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F` is declared as pointer to function with no parameters returning `void`. But your functions return `int`, and are member functions of `MemberClass` rather than plain ordinary functions. So the type you need is

```
typedef int (MemberClass::*F)();
```

Calling it is also more interesting:

```
int result = (mclass->*f[index])();
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: rather than a method pointer, use C++11's `functional` library.

I'm butchering OP's sample code slightly to simplify the example.

MemberClass stays mostly the same. I removed the member variables because the methods are now hard-coded to return 1 and 2 to make them easy to tell apart.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class MemberClass
{
public:
    int GetValue1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int GetValue2()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};
```

`myClass` gets a rip-up because this is where the action is.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
```

I'm using an array of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of a typedef and an array of the typedef. Note the template argument `int()`. This is an array of functions that takes nothing and returns an `int`. [Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_(programming)) in [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) will provide the hidden `this` parameter required by methods. If the function has parameters that are not known at the time of binding, use [`std::placeholders`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) to save room to them in the method's parameter list.

Since the methods are bound to their object, there is no longer any need to store `MemberClass* mclass;`

```
    std::function<int()> f[2]; 

public:
```

Calling the function is simple: index the array and stick the brackets on.

```
    int Process(int index)
    {
        return f[index]();
    }
```

The constructor is either a bit trickier, or less tricky, depending on your school of thought. I'm using an initializer list because it is cleaner (to me, at anyrate) and often has performance advantages. For one thing, you can swap out the array for a std::vector or most other containers without having to change a line of code other than the variable definition.

```
f[0] = std::bind(&MemberClass::GetValue1, mem); 
f[1] =...
```

inside the body of the constructor is still an option.

```
    MyClass(MemberClass * mem):
        f{std::bind(&MemberClass::GetValue1, mem), 
          std::bind(&MemberClass::GetValue2, mem)}
    {
    }

};
```

And a silly little bit of test code to make sure this all works. Why? Because every time you don't test code in it's simplest form you're taking an unnecessary risk. If it doesn't work small, it won't work big.

```
int main()
{
    MemberClass c;
    MyClass d(&c);
    std::cout << d.Process(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << d.Process(1) << std::endl;
}
```

All together for one cut and paste-able block:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class MemberClass
{

public:

    int GetValue1()
    {

        return 1;
    }

    int GetValue2()
    {

        return 2;
    }

};

class MyClass
{

private:
    std::function<int()> f[2];
public:
    int Process(int index)
    {
        return f[index]();
    }

    MyClass(MemberClass * mem):
        f{std::bind(&MemberClass::GetValue1, mem), 
          std::bind(&MemberClass::GetValue2, mem)}
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
    MemberClass c;
    MyClass d(&c);
    std::cout << d.Process(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << d.Process(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks, so the poiinter to memberclass is needed in myclass anyways for different purposes. Another high preference is when a call to d.process(0) is made, it should have the least and minimum performance hit, ideally no worse than a regular function call. Is this the case with your code?The initialization part can be slow, thats not a problem.

Comment: also theoretically, why cant a simple f[0] = &MemberClass::GetValue1 work?

Comment: Minimal runtime hit. Most of the grunt work is taken care of by the compiler when the template is specialized, and after that it should resolve down to  a pointer dereference and the usual function call overhead.

Comment: `f[0] = &MemberClass::GetValue1` can work if `f` is of the right type. The important bit is `f[0]` needs to know  that it is a pointer to a Class's member function and needs a hidden `this` parameter. I'm over simplifying a little here, but `int GetValue1()` is actually closer to `int GetValue1(MemberClass * this)` and won't fit into `void(*F)();` [For more details, read this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types). For usage, see Alan Stokes's answer.

Comment: ofcourse, the hidden this in function call. May I know the benefit of std::bind over function pointer? I am very performance sensitive

Comment: Bind is used to keep a function with one or more of it's parameters. The only bookkeeping you have to do is ensure no one `delete`s any of the bound parameters. Here is an example of bind being used to make a random number generator easy to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059976/my-program-loops-forever-and-does-only-a-half-of-what-i-told-it-to-do/31061880#31061880