# How to get value of enums when filling struct/class

Tags: c++, struct, enums

I got this quite hard thing to do for me as a beginner... I want to fill this struct with information which would randomly generated

```
struct bunny {
bool is_vampire;
std::string name;
std::string color;
char gender;
int age;
int birth_date;
};
```

I wanted to use enums for example

```
enum colors{white, brown, black, spotted};
```

When I would initialize some struct I would make a function

```
void struct_fill(bunny x)
{   
x.is_vampire = rand()%2;
x.color = colors(rand() % 11);
..... etc.
}
```

But I thought that if I use a number it would return value that that number represents
/which in case of lets say number 2 would be black/
... Is there any simple solution to this? Or other way to fill the struct with data randomly chosen from some amount of choices?
*I apologize for my english

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: Since `color` is of type `std::string` you cannot do that with an enum. You'll need something like a `std::vector<std::string>` and randomly select an index.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess I missunderstood why do enums exist and used it in a way they are made for, thanks

Comment: Are you looking to convert `enum` to text?

Comment: You could change the type for `color` from `string` to `colors`.

Comment: I am trying to give several bunnies random colors, I wanted to use enumerations because I though I could generated random number which would be index of some word in enum and it would print lets say spotted or black or any color

Comment: And I dont have any error message, it just prints out number but I want it to print text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple ways to do the colour trick. The simplest is probably

```
std::vector<std::string> colors{"white", "brown", "black", "spotted"};
```

and then

```
x.color = colors[rand() % colors.size()];
```

Since colors is unlikely to change at runtime, an array of `std::string` (or even `const char *`) might be more efficient. Bit trickier to get the size, though.

While I'm at it, can I talk you into [giving `std::uniform_int_distribution` a read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to see if it's a better fit for you than `rand`?

Comment: Hey, thank you ! I got it working,I looked on the uniform_int_distribution and is there any other difference between rand other than you can use any int interval you want ? Anyway it looks better than rand I guess, thanks once more.

Comment: The big difference is something you probably won't care much about at this point: The newer random number generators are much better than the old ones. `rand` was designed to solve problems back in the 1970s. Odds are pretty good that in 2050 `uniform_int_distribution` will be seen as a tool fit only for barbarians.

Comment: Okay, ill start using uniform_int_distribution. Thanks

Comment: Wait, I am trying to use the uniform thingy and its quite.. a lot stuff to type etc and I dont know what they mean and cant find succesful answer.. when I type `std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 1);` and then `dis(gen)` and then I have only number from 0 to 1.. if I want to have different interval on line under i have to type  `std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 5);` again ? And then  `dis(gen)` ?.. looks overly complicated

Comment: @Kajm If you need two distributions, make two. `std::uniform_int_distribution<> disZeroOne(0, 1);` and `std::uniform_int_distribution<> disZeroFive(0, 5);` To keepo things simple, I set it up something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31061880/4581301

Comment: Problem is that I need a lot of distributions and this method looks kinda messy. I would have to have too many of lines just to declare distributions. Maybe I could fill it into a function which would change interval of the distribution ?

Comment: Could do that, but then you're creating distributions over and over. Speed-wise you're better off creating once and re-using. Should only be one line of code per distribution. `auto ZeroOne = std::bind ( std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,1), engine ); auto ZeroTen = std::bind ( std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,10), engine );`