# C++ Die class which have 3 similar sides

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I am trying to create a DIE class. The thing is the die need to have 3 same sides. So 1 1 1 2 3 4 . I don't really know how to implement that. I also have to keep track of the percentage of how much time it rolled the numbers. So Far I have this and I am kinda stuck .

**Die.H**

```
                #pragma once
            #include <iostream>
            #include <string>

            using namespace std;
            class Die
            {
            public:
                Die();
                ~Die();
                Die(int numSide);
                int roll();
                int rollPercentage();

            private:
                int side;
            };
```

**Die.cpp**

```
        #include "Die.h"



        Die::Die()
        {
        }


        Die::~Die()
        {
        }


        Die::Die() :side(6) {}

        Die::Die(int numSide) : side(numSide) {}

        int Die::roll() {
            return rand() % side + 1;
        }
```

And then in the main I will simply create a die . Something like this.

```
        Die die;
        cout << die.roll();
        cout << die.roll;
```

Just not sure how to implement 3 same sides and keep track.Without classes I made this. But I am not sure how to implement it with a class.

```
 int arr[] = { 0, 0 , 0, 1, 2, 3 };
            int random;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                random = rand() % 6;
                cout << arr[random] << " ";
            }
```

Comment: You get a number between `1` and `6` currently, right? Now how to make the max value be `4`? Perhaps it can be done with simple arithmetic? And since no value can be less than `1`, you could have a quick condition to make sure about that. And you will automatically have three "sides" being `1`.

Comment: Or using the technique you have already experimented with, just put the code into the `roll` function? Minus the loop and with a return instead of `cout`.

Comment: Wow. I didn't think about putting the experimenting code into the roll function. It works! Thanks. Any suggestions about keeping track of the percentage of numbers rolled?

Comment: Keep track of all of the throws, maybe in an array where array[0] is the number of 1s thrown etc.  Then array[0]/sum(array) is the percentage.

Comment: Unrelated: A more modern approach to random dice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31061880/4581301

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Die
{
public:
    // note rand() is deprecated
    int roll() { return _side[rand() % 6]; }

private:
    std::array<int, 6> _side = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> rolls;

    // keep track of all the rolls
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; ++x)
        rolls.push_back(Die{}.roll());

    // how many rolls were ones?
    double ones = std::count(
        rolls.begin(),
        rolls.end(),
        1);

    cout << "1 rolled " << 100 * (ones / rolls.size()) << "% of the time.\n";

    // repeat above for 2, 3, 4, etc.
    return 0;
}
```